# Dropbox photos and "date taken"

Tags: java, photo, dropbox-api

I have a question. I'm using Dropbox sdk for java to do small project (extract from pom.xml).

```
<groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
<artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
<version>[1.7,1.8)</version>
```

What I try to do, is to get a "date taken" metadata from file uploaded to dropbox. I have seen that this info is avaiable from dropbox (it is mentioned for example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata)). But I was unable to find this info in api for java. I would be grateful if anyone will help/advice something me with this issue.

My current code responisble for listing files from dropbox looks like this:

```
        DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren(path);
        for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
            //Some logic inhere
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found an answer: my problem was SDK version. In version that I used (1.7) there was no such thing (you can check it [here](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.File.html)).

However, when you update your version to 1.8 then you can find it: [DbxEntry.File.PhotoInfo](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.8.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.File.PhotoInfo.html)